# Outlook Addin - Hide Help on Hover

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I've created a custom add in for Outlook 2010.  When I hover over the button, there's a help section with a cog image that says **Press F1 for Add-in Help**.  I would like to remove this so it's not visible when the user hovers over the button but can't find where/how to do so.

[image: Outlook Add In Hover Help]

Answer (score 0):

The Office extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. You can try to use Windows API functions to get the job done.